# Getting sizes of html tags

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I'm use development tools' link in Chrome I can select any tag(in source code) and info about chosen element are displayed(image below). I need write script that can do the same operation. How I can get width and height for every tag in a source code. Any idea?
[image].

Comment: Do you want individual function or all in a common function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's this lovely [getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getBoundingClientRect) function. No need for jQuery. Works in every browser.

```
var rect = document.getElementById('foobar').getBoundingClientRect();

console.log(rect.width);
console.log(rect.height);
console.log(rect.left);
console.log(rect.right);
console.log(rect.top);
console.log(rect.bottom);
```

Comment: This work, but I want to know: Can I use this function in https Web site in any way? When I try it on google site i get warning:[blocked] The page at https://www.google.com.ua/ ran insecure content from http://192.168.0.100/myscript.js.

Comment: How do you insert your script there?

Comment: Using bookmarklet javascript:(function(){var s = document.createElement('script');s.src = 'http://192.168.0.100/myscript.js';document.body.appendChild(s);})(); and after it pasted it in myscript.js file

Comment: This is not related to your question. Your browser settings disallow scripts from a non-secure (non-ssl) page to be loaded inside a secure page.

Answer (score 3):

You know [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)? With this library, you can retrieve:

```
$('#element').innerWidth(); ---> width of #element's content + padding
$('#element').width(); ---> width of #element including padding and borders
$('#element').outerWidth(); ---> width of #element + padding + borders + margins
```

Same stuff for height:

```
$('#element').innerHeight(); ---> height of #element's content + padding
$('#element').height(); ---> height of #element including padding and borders
$('#element').outerHeight(); ---> height of #element + padding + borders + margins
```